# No Sound on desktop

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

I just installed the latest version of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my new desktop computer. The computer is connected to monitor via HDMI - DVI cable. Neither can I hear system sound nor any audio from music videos on YouTube.

Please help!

I have tried reinstalling pavucontorl couple of times, selected the HDMI output in pulse audio but still no sound.

Note that I have 2 different versions of pulse audio installed. I don't believe it must be problem but if it then please suggest how to delete the old version.

Further in the configuration tab of pulse audio, I see options as 'HDMI Output (unplugged) (unavailable)'.
Is this the reason of any drivers being not installed?

Please help me with the sound.

Comment: Does the monitor have speakers? If you unplug the HDMI, does your desktop output sound to speakers through its audio jack? Do headphones work? Just out of curiosity, how did you end up with two versions of pulse audio? Finally, have you tried another HDMI cable just to be sure?

Comment: Dear @jwcooper:  thank you for the message, My monitor does not have speakers. But yes, the front panel headphones do have sound output. I assumed it wont have and did not check it. Thank you.

I ended up with 2 versions of pulse audio while trying a solution but now I have just one version. 

yes, I did try this HDMI cable for another machine and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

> The computer is connected to monitor via HDMI - DVI cable

It's impossible for audio over HDMI to be converted to audio over DVI with an adapter.  While both HDMI and DVI both can carry an audio stream, they are not compatible *with each other* so you cannot pass sound thru a HDMI to DVI *adapter*.

[image: Popular video connectors]

You will either need to use an HDMI to HDMI cable, or DVI to DVI.  Many DVI cables and ports also do not support audio over DVI, so every "link in the chain" (all ports and cables) must have the capability to support audio over DVI.  All HDMI cables should have this capability.

Comment: Dear @Nmath thank you for the answer. My monitor only has VGA and DVI-D; while my CPU has HDMI only. this is the reason the cable is HDMI - DVI.

Is there any workaround??

Comment: I can hear audio for mp3 songs and youtube videos using headphones on front panel. My monitor does not have speaker. Should the onboard audio not work with display using an HDMI DVI cable?

Comment: If you are running and HDMI cable, my understanding is that it will also push the audio over the cable by default. If you want the audio to come out of attached speakers or an internal pc speaker instead, you will need to select that from the audio menu (little speaker icon) at the top of the screen. It should be set to HDMI, so just click the drop down menu and change to another output. Here's a link with pictures and instructions: [Change audio device)[https://rastating.github.io/setting-default-audio-device-in-ubuntu-18-04/]

Comment: Hello @jwcooper: I already the option of selecting HDMI output but it does not help. I am not able to get audio from PC.
The link you gave does not work :(

Comment: Sorry, the link didnt copy correctly. Here it is: https://tinyurl.com/y54cjlvt  I was actually saying to select another audio output other than HDMI since your monitor doesnt have speakers. Without speakers, there wont be any sound from the monitor so try to push the sound to another interface.

Comment: ** pactl list short sinks 

14 alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.iec958-stereo module-alsa-card.c s16le 2ch 44100Hz SUSPENDED


***pactl list short sources
14 alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.iec958-stereo.monitor module-alsa-card.c s16le 2ch 44100Hz SUSPENDED


Above are the results of the commands.

Does the SUSPENDED mean anything?? Since I have just one item in the list for both the commands, Am I still suppose to change the default.pa file??

Comment: Hard to tell from your comment, but those entries should be numbered. You want to select the one that says "monitor". You can use `pactl set-default-sink NumOfMonitor` where NumOfMonitor is the number of that output in the list. It would be significantly easier just to use the GUI though. It has a dropdown menu you can use to select the output you want. You shouldn't have to use the command line and would probably avoid accidentally messing with anything else. If that doesnt work, you can follow the directions in link to remove and re-install alsa: https://zillowtech.com/ubuntu-no-sound.html